# Problema com substituição de argumento na função

Tags: python, python-3.x, funções

Estou com um problema com os argumentos que passo na função abaixo, estou tentando passar o argumento **sha512** para **hash_type**, para que assim no código dentro da função seja feita a substituição, e assim o **hash_target** seria passado pelo algoritmo de hash correto, porém sempre que executo o código, o python retorna uma mensagem de erro dizendo que a biblioteca **hashlib** não tem função **hash_type**, o que mostra que a substituição não está acontecendo, o que pode ser feito para arrumar este problema ?

Código:

```
import sys
import hashlib


def main(hash_type,wordlist='palavrasptbr'):
    hash_target = input("Hash :\n")
    hash_target = bytes(hash_target.encode('utf-8'))
    wordlist += '.txt'
    archive = open(wordlist, 'r')
    print(archive)

    hash_target = bytes(hash_target)

    print(hashing_sha512(bytes(hash_target)))

def hashing_sha512(hash_target):
    hashing = hashlib.sha512()
    hashing.update(hash_target)
    return hashing.hexdigest()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        main(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

Comment: posta o codigo completo bença

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro: o seu código não funciona sem modificações. Não é uma boa forma de
pedir ajuda.

1. Na sua funação `main` o argumento `hash_type` não é utilizado.
2. Você carrega o arquivo em `archive = open(wordlist, 'r')` mas não o utiliza.

Tente um approach diferente:

1. Faça com que o seu argv[1] seja uma string que te mapeie uma função:

   ```
   if argv[1] == 'sha512':
       hashfunc = hashlib.sha512
   ```